# Editing WinForms RichTextBoxControl C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can you add text to a RichTextBox control and change the font style as you add text?

Comment: The answer might be to configure the text string to display into an RTF format and set the controls RTF property.  Is there a simple way to create an RTF formatted string such as an RtfStringBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an excellent library on Code Project which provides an [RTFStringBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/RTFBuilder.aspx) which allows the settings of formatting as the stringbuilder is built up.  Setting the RichTextBox's RTF property to the RTFStringBuilder.ToString() does just the job I need.  Thanks seeblunt!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean add text programmatically....

RichTextBox myTB = new RichTextBox();

myTB.Text += "Some text";

-- or --

myTB.AppendText("Some other Text");

As for changing the font, you could add an event handler to your richtextbox to get notified when the text changes.

myTB.TextChanged += new EventHandler(myTB_TextChanged);

and set the font of myTB in that event handler.

Just a thought.

Comment: I do want to add the text programmatically as in youre first example but I want to cahnge the style of the font as the text is being added so that the text box displays the text in a mixed formats (i.e. some words are bold some are not).